# Is there an edit control for Delphi that allows path editing?

Tags: delphi, path, explorer, edit-control

I have various hierarchical structures and would like to allow navigation around then using an editor like the Microsoft one found in the explorer address bar below. Is there such a Delphi component? (Paid for or free)?

[image]

Comment: I think I might just write one, just for fun, you know...

Comment: @Andreas - isn't that address bar hidden in some shell interface ? It would be easist way to implement it.

Comment: @daemon_x: Very good point. Still, not as fun as writing your own, which I am currently working on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TAdvExplorerTreeview from TMS might be what your looking for:

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advexptree.asp

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Haven't tried by myself but [Roy Klever's PathViewer](http://rmklever.com/?p=231) component looks quite interesting.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have spent the morning writing such a control. Actually, I wrote a very generic, completely virtual base control, from which I later derived a directory browser control:

[image: Hierarchy of breadcrumb controls]

The source code is published [here](https://privat.rejbrand.se/breadcrumbs.html)

Here are some images:

**`Style := bbsClassic`**

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

**`Style := bbsFlat`**

[image: Screenshot]

**`Style := bbsHeader`**

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

**`Style := bbsThemed`**

[image: Screenshot]

**`Style := bbsCommand`**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 Andreas, great work, maybe is better, if you publish your code in the code google hosting site.

Comment: Also, I've only just realised that the little arrows drop down a menu in Windows. I've only ever clicked on the word....

Comment: +10 For the effort, the time spent, the completeness of the implementation, and the generosity. -9 by SO ;)

Comment: Thank you, @NGLN, but really, I'm the real winner, because I think it is so fun to write visual controls!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'd very much like to try on BCB2009 but I seem to have difficulties compiling the component.  [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'PathCanonicalizeW' referenced from ...
Is mentioned code your latest version ?

Comment: How about a overview page for your various components? I know there are some, but I can't get from BreadcrumbBar to another one.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about anything exactly like that but the BergSoft Next Collection includes a path control similar to that (useful for breadcrumb trails and the like)

http://www.bergsoft.net/component/next-collection/overview.htm

It's free providing you don't want access to the source. Source is pretty cheap though and it's a one off cost that'll get you all future updates.